# SQL Finding Percent of two counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking at a database that contains information about orders.  I am trying to determine the % of orders that exceed 14 days from the time they are ordered until the time they are shipped.  I am having a hard time creating a column of the % per month. Right now I have

```
 Select ol.orderid, ol.productid, Month(ol.shipdate) as monthShipped,
       Year(ol.shipdate)as yearShipped, 
       (Select Count(*) From orderline ol Where datediff(ol.shipdate,o.orderdate)> 14 Group By Month(ol.shipdate), Year(ol.shipdate))/Count(*) as percentage
 From orderline ol
 Join orders o 
    on ol.orderid = o.orderid
 Group By monthShipped, yearShipped
 Order By yearShipped, monthShipped
```

I get an error saying my subquery returns more than one row.  Dont I want more than one row? If I removed the     Group By in the subquery then I get value but it is nowhere close to right.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. Thank you.

Comment: @John How did you come to decide that this question was about MySQL and not SQL Server? Maybe ask instead of just assuming. :-) Looks more like SQL Server to me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Newer developers tend to gravitate to MySQL so it was an educated guess. :) But if you think I got it wrong definitely make the appropriate changes.

Comment: @John the only clue I'm seeing now is the bizarre datediff syntax that MySQL allows, where you don't have to specify the unit. Otherwise, I'd just ask and leave the editing for when you have confirmation.

Comment: OP - please put the sample tables and some sample rows. It makes it easy to help.

Comment: @AaronBertrand What's ironic is I typically do but this time I felt confident enough it was MySQL to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that the `shipdate` is for each order line.  Let me assume that you mean the *latest* ship date per order.  The following gets this information at the order level:

```
 Select ol.orderid, max(ol.shipdate) as lastshipdate
 From orderline ol
 Group By ol.orderid;
```

To get the difference, you need the orders:

```
 Select ol.orderid, datediff(o.orderdate, max(ol.shipdate) ) as diff
 From orders o join
      orderline ol
      on o.orderid = ol.orderid
 Group By ol.orderid;
```

Finally, to get the number and percentage by month:

```
select year(orderdate), month(orderdate),
       count(*) as numorders, sum(diff > 14) as numdelayed, avg(diff > 14) as p_dealyed
from (Select ol.orderid, datediff(o.orderdate, max(ol.shipdate) ) as diff, o.orderdate
      From orders o join
           orderline ol
           on o.orderid = ol.orderid
      Group By ol.orderid
     ) o
group by year(orderdate), month(orderdate)
order by 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st query returns the % of order line items that were shipped more than 14 days after the order was placed grouped by month shipped.

```
select monthShipped, yearShipped,
    (sum(greater_than_14)/count(*)) percent_exceeding_14
from (
    select
        month(ol.shipdate) as monthShipped,
        year(ol.shipdate) as yearShipped,    
        (datediff(ol.shipdate,o.orderdate) > 14) greater_than_14
    from orderline ol
    join orders o on ol.orderid = o.orderid    
) t1 group by monthShipped, yearShipped
```

The 2nd query returns the % of orders where at least 1 order line item was shipped more than 14 days after the order was placed grouped by month ordered.

```
select monthOrdered, yearOrdered,
    (count(g14)/count(*)) percent_exceeding_14
from (
    select 
        month(orderdate) monthOrdered, 
        year(orderdate) yearOrdered,
        greater_than_14.orderid g14
    from orders o left join (
        select orderid
        from orders o2
        where exists (
            select 1 from orderline ol
            where ol.orderid = o2.orderid
            and datediff(ol.shipdate,o2.orderdate) > 14
        )
    ) greater_than_14 on greater_than_14.orderid = o.orderid
) t1 group by monthOrdered, yearOrdered
```